# Random walk on the edges of a square

Tags: probability, random-walk

A bug is at one corner of a square. What's the
expectation of the number of steps it takes, to reach the opposite corner? Each step takes it to an
adjacent corner, with either corner equally likely.

Comment: See [this](https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=random+walk+cube) for ideas

Answer (score 3):

What you describe is a discrete circular random walk with four points.  (The fact that it is arranged as a square instead of a circle does not affect the behaviour.)  Let $E_1$ and $E_2$ denote the expected number of steps to get to a point that is one or two points away from the starting point respectively.  Drawing the four points, and using the [law of total probability](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_total_probability) conditioning on the first move clearly gives:

$$\begin{equation} \begin{aligned}
E_1 &= \frac{1}{2} \times 1 + \frac{1}{2} \times (1+E_2), \\[8pt]
E_2 &= \frac{1}{2} \times (1+E_1) + \frac{1}{2} (1+E_1).
\end{aligned} \end{equation}$$

Have a think about why these equations should hold, having regard to the two directions the bug could move on the first step.  Once you understand this, it should be quite simple to solve these two simultaneous equations to find the expected number of steps $E_2$.

Comment: +1.  A little more thought suggests working two steps at a time, because the bug's position after an even number of steps can be only where it started or at the opposite corner, resulting in a geometric distribution for *half* the number of steps needed to reach the opposite corner.

Comment: Good point - that gets you $E_2$ very easily.